# "length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent" error in linear regression summary in r

Tags: r, regression, r-caret

I'm running a straightforward linear regression model fit on the following dataframe:

```
> str(model_data_rev)
'data.frame':   128857 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ ENTRY_4 : num  186 218 208 235 256 447 471 191 207 250 ...
 $ ENTRY_8 : num  724 769 791 777 707 237 236 726 773 773 ...
 $ ENTRY_12: num  2853 2989 3174 3027 3028 ...
 $ ENTRY_16: num  2858 3028 3075 2992 3419 ...
 $ ENTRY_20: num  7260 7188 7587 7560 7165 ...
 $ EXIT_4  : num  70 82 105 114 118 204 202 99 73 95 ...
 $ EXIT_8  : num  1501 1631 1594 1576 1536 ...
 $ EXIT_12 : num  3862 3923 4158 3970 3895 ...
 $ EXIT_16 : num  1559 1539 1737 1681 1795 ...
 $ EXIT_20 : num  2145 2310 2217 2330 2291 ...
 $ DAY     : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "Sun"<"Mon"<"Tues"<..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ MONTH   : Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Jan"<"Feb"<"Mar"<..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

I split the data in to training and test sets as follows using the caret package:

```
split<-createDataPartition(y = model_data_rev$EXIT_20, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
d_training = model_data_rev[split,]
d_test = model_data_rev[-split,]
```

I train the model using the train function in the caret package:

```
ctrl<-trainControl(method = 'cv',number = 5)
lmCVFit<-train(EXIT_20 ~ ., data = d_training, method = 'lm', trControl = ctrl, metric='Rsquared')
summary(lmCVFit)
```

When I run `summary(lmCVFit)` I get the following error:

```
Error in summary.lm(object$finalModel, ...) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(est, se, tval, 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

I thought it might be the related to the my initial dataframe above. Specifically, i thought it could have to do with the factor variables.  So I cut them off (not shown), ran everything again, and got the same error.

I also ran the regression without CV using the 'lm' function in R and got the same error when I ran summary()

Has anyone seen this and can anyone help?  I can't find anything on line that speaks to this error in the context of regression.

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

I modified the ordinal variable to standard character variables.  Structure now looks like this:

```
> str(model_data_rev)
'data.frame':   128857 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ ENTRY_4 : num  186 218 208 235 256 447 471 191 207 250 ...
 $ ENTRY_8 : num  724 769 791 777 707 237 236 726 773 773 ...
 $ ENTRY_12: num  2853 2989 3174 3027 3028 ...
 $ ENTRY_16: num  2858 3028 3075 2992 3419 ...
 $ ENTRY_20: num  7260 7188 7587 7560 7165 ...
 $ EXIT_4  : num  70 82 105 114 118 204 202 99 73 95 ...
 $ EXIT_8  : num  1501 1631 1594 1576 1536 ...
 $ EXIT_12 : num  3862 3923 4158 3970 3895 ...
 $ EXIT_16 : num  1559 1539 1737 1681 1795 ...
 $ EXIT_20 : num  2145 2310 2217 2330 2291 ...
 $ DAY     : Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 2 6 7 5 1 3 4 2 6 7 ...
 $ MONTH   : Factor w/ 12 levels "April","August",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
```

I still get the error when running summary after fitting the model.

It is also important emphasize that the model fitting works without throwing an error.  It is summary() that is throwing off the error.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the Day and Month in your lm formula (both of which are factors) is causing the issue. Run model.matrix on your lm formula to see if the inclusion of the 7 + 12 levels screw up your available df.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  As indicated I took them out and ran everything again with only the continuous variables.  Same result.  Will try model.matrix and report back

Comment: Try `dput(model_data_rev)` or rather `dput(d_training)`

Comment: Ran `dput(d_training)`.  Still get same error.

Comment: dput is to write out your data in a reproducible form (which was what i thought you were asking before you edited your comment. To get your model. matrix,  run `model.matrix(EXIT_20 ~ ., data = d_training)`

Comment: ok.  I have the model matrix.  how do I reincorporate into the regression?

Comment: You're not supposed to. The model.matrix is formed when you're running your regression. The error "length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent" is caused due to the number of dimnames you assign is not equal to the number of rows in the matrix. The model.matrix you'd form could potentially highlight why the error is there.

Comment: Not clear on the model.matrix syntax.  incorporated it above (possibly incorrectly) within the regression function.  since model.matrix encompasses the formula and data set - i get an error saying there is no y variable.

Comment: I had this error occur and I can't work out where it came from either. In my case, it was something as innocuous as: `summary(lm(mpg~wt, data=mtcars))` Restarting the `rstudio` instance fixed it.