# In R quantreg: Length of dimnames not equal to array extent

Tags: r, quantreg

I'm new to R; trying to figure out `quantreg` and running into what may be a simple error. I am following, more or less exactly, the example code provided in the quantreg help file (and many other online sources), but with my data set rather than a sample data set. I run the following code:

```
library(quantreg)
rq.xy.1 <- rq(y~-1+x1+x2+d1,tau=1:99/100,data=xy.df,na.action=na.omit,model=TRUE)
s2 <- summary(rq.xy.1,se="boot")
plot.summary.rqs(s2)
```

The first lines execute fine. On the final line (using `plot.summary.rqs`) I get an error message:

> Error in `rownames`<-``(`*tmp*`, value = c("x1", "x2", "d1")) : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

I have not determined the source of the error. Here is what I have figured out so far:

- I can produce a figure without confidence bands just fine; that is, I can run `plot.rqs(rq.xy.1)` and return a plot of coefficients (over quantiles) for each explanatory variable. But I want the confidence bands.
- Object `rq.xy.1` is an object of class `rqs` (the output of `rq` is an object of class `rq`, `rqs` or `rq.process` and this one is an `rqs`).
- Object `s2` is an object of class `summary.rqs`.
- That means `s2` is a list (I think? -- that's what I see in the Environment pane of RStudio); not sure if this is significant; I did scan it to see if there's a useful indicator of the length of something called `dimnames` and didn't see anything that seemed obviously useful
- I called `traceback()` (based on reading another online help thread) but that didn't produce anything that seemed useful either.
- I tried `model.matrix(y~-1+x1+x2+d1, data=xy.df` (based on reading ["length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent" error in linear regression summary in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201142/length-of-dimnames-1-not-equal-to-array-extent-error-in-linear-regression)) but again, that did not give me any clues. I think that's because the error is getting thrown in `plot.summary.rqs` rather than `summary`. If I can use `model.matrix` to uncover the source of my error, I do not understand how and I would appreciate advice here.

At this point I'm pretty stuck. I've searched many sources and just can't figure out this error. Thanks for your help.

Edits to original question below this line:

Edit 1. A subset of my data (minimal to reproduce the problem) is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mges3kuro6ty5s/tmp_data?dl=0

Edit 2. I explored the problem more using several subsets of the data. Here is some info that may help. There are basically four types of rows in my dataframe. I'll label them by capital letters for easy reference:

- A: y, x1, x2 are all NA. d1=0
- B: y, x1, x2 are all NA. d1=1
- C: y, x1, x2 are all numeric (continuous). d1=1
- D: y, x1, x2 are all numeric (continuous). d1=0

It appears that the presence of one or more rows of type D is sufficient to generate the error I noted in the question above. (Also, if all of the rows are type D, then rq() fails because the design matrix is singular.) This is curious. quantreg ought to work fine when one of the explanatory variables is 0/1 (and indeed, rq() does work fine). What is it about plot.summary.rqs() that throws an error when one of the explanatory variables is a dummy (with variation)?

Edit 3. I figured out how to solve the problem, again exploring those subsets. I still don't understand the reason for the error, but I can avoid the problem by including a constant in the estimating equation:

```
library(quantreg)
rq.xy.1 <- rq(y~x1+x2+d1,tau=1:99/100,data=xy.df,na.action=na.omit,model=TRUE)
s2 <- summary(rq.xy.1,se="boot")
plot.summary.rqs(s2)
```

As I thought more about the relationship I am trying to assess, I came to see that including the constant was econometrically the correct approach also. Thus, I consider this problem solved (for now anyway).

Thanks, Jimbou, for your help - as noted, I'm quite new to R, and trying to figure out how to provide a minimal dataset was what turned me on to trying to reproduce the problem with subsets of my data. If I hadn't tried that, I wouldn't have made the observations in Edit 2 above, and probably would not have come to this happy conclusion.

Comment: Did you tried `plot(summary(rq.xy.1,se="boot"))`

Comment: Yes. That returned the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your sample data `xy.df` using `dput()` for instance